# Excel Power Query -- Select value in column specified in related table -- INDEX+MATCH alternative

Tags: excel, powerquery

**Problem**

I have two queries, one contains product data (*data_query*), the other (*recode_query*) contains product names from within the *data_query* and assigns them specific id_tags. id_tags are also column names within the *data_query*.

**What I need to achieve and fail at**

I need the *data_query* to look at the id_tag of the specific product name within the *data_query*, as parsed from the *recode_query* (this is already working and in place) and input the retrieved value within the specific custom column cell. In Excel, I would be using `INDEX/MATCH` combo:

```
{=INDEX(data_query[#Data];; MATCH(data_query[@id_tag]; data_query[#Headers]; 0))}
```

I have searched near and far, but I probably can't even spot the solution, even if I have come across it, as I am not that deep in the data manipulation and power query myself.

Comment: Apologies if I'm getting confused, but isn't this something you can use a simple `VLOOKUP` for?

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but that is not a "clean" solution for me, as I am parsing results from the power query back into Excel data sheet to summarize within a pivot table and want the data to be fully processed within power query, as to minimize the input factor of someone else working with the data. I want them to just assign the id_tag/column name to individual product names, which then power query matches and outputs. I don't know, if I'm explaining myself better or confusing you more.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're wanting?

```
let
    DataQuery = Table.FromColumns({{1,2,3}, {"Boxed", "Bagged", "Rubberbanded"}}, {"ID","Pkg"}),
    RecodeQuery = Table.FromColumns({{"Squirt Gun", "Coffee Maker", "Trenching Tool"}, {1,2,3}}, {"Prod Name", "ID2"}),
    Rzlt = Table.Join(DataQuery, "ID", RecodeQuery, "ID2", JoinKind.Inner)
in
    Rzlt
```